# check if value already exists in db

Tags: laravel

I have an insert form and a dropdownbox which displays all cars names and when selected one it saves the id in column "car_id" which is unique. What I want is to check if this id already exists and if yes to display a validation message:
create controller

```
public function create() {  
   $cars = DB::table('cars')->orderBy('Description', 'asc')->distinct()->lists('Description', 'id');
   return View::make('pages.insur_docs_create', array(
      'cars' => $cars
   ));
}
```

insur_docs_blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('car', 'Car', array('class'=>'control-label col-lg-4')) }}
   <div class="col-lg-8">
      {{ Form::select('car', $cars, Input::old('class'), array(
         'data-validation' => 'required', 
         'data-validation-error-msg' => 'You did not enter a valid car',
         'class' => 'form-control')) 
      }}
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's Validator class for this. These are a few snippits of how it works. This methods works by using your data model. Instead of writing everything out I added a few links that provide you all the information to complete your validation.

```
$data = Input::all();

$rules = array(
    'car_id' => 'unique'
);

$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

if ($validator->passes()) {
    return 'Data was saved.';
}
```

- http://laravelbook.com/laravel-input-validation
- http://laravel.com/docs/validation
- http://daylerees.com/codebright/validation

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's "exists" method like this:

```
if (User::where('email', $email)->exists()) {
   // that email already exists in the users table
}
```